# Promises.all() breaking sequential chaining

Tags: javascript, promise

In the past I've used the jQuery deffered/promises, but I'm trying to move to javascript Promises. I have a function that needs to make several network calls in sequence and then several that can happen in any order, but all need to resolve before moving forward. I start with the sequential calls and they go in order, but then with the results of the second call I need to iterate over those results and make a variable number (at the moment 6) of further calls. I don't care what order those are done in, but do need to wait for all of them to resolve before I proceed. I thought this pattern would work. But it doesn't.

```
function doLotsOfStuff(){

    firstNetworkCall()
        .then(function(data){
            // do stuff with data
            return secondNetworkCall();
        })
        .then(function(data){
            // do stuff with data

            var promises = data.map(function(item){
                // All of these calls (happens to be 6)
                // need to be done before I continue
                return thirdIndependentCall(item.Info);
            });

            // at this point I see [Promise, Promise, ....]
            // all are unresolved

            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then(function(results){
            // executes immediately after the Promises.all() line
            // none of them are resolved
            // results is just one unresolved promise
        });
}
```

I can chain the final step onto the Promises.all() like this

```
return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function(results){
            // this works!
         })
```

But if I want to chain more things after that I have to keep stepping them in. Seems like I'm missing some piece of information.

**EDIT**

I had copied over a typo in my simplified code which isn't in my actual code. The suggestion to add a `.catch()` in my chain was a good one and I tried it. Now it throws `firstNetworkCall(...).then(...).then(...).catch is not a function.`

I think the problem is that some of my code (somewhere) is still relying on `jQuery.Deffered` and that doesn't play well with Promise.

It is good to know that my initial pattern should work -- if I'm consistent with what kind of async handling I'm working with.

Comment: The code you are showing should work as expected.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you mean by *"if I want to chain more things after that I have to keep stepping them in"*?

Comment: Is the `s` in `Promises.all` a typo? Seems like that should be an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
Promises.all(promises)
```

to this:

```
Promise.all(promises)
```

What you have is throwing an exception (because `Promises` is not defined which is caught by the `.then()` and then rejects the promise chain.

This is a classic reason why you should always have a `.catch()` at the end of your chain because if you were logging that rejection, it would have probably told you what the error was.

---

If you want to convert any jQuery promises to ES6 promises so you can use `.catch()` anywhere or to just guarantee consistent behavior, you can wrap them with `Promise.resolve()` as in:

```
       Promise.resolve(firstNetworkCall()).then(...).catch(...)
```

or this:

```
       var promises = data.map(function(item) {
            // All of these calls (happens to be 6)
            // need to be done before I continue
            return Promise.resolve(thirdIndependentCall(item.Info));
        });

        // at this point I see [Promise, Promise, ....]
        // all are unresolved

        return Promise.all(promises);
```

And, keep in mind that some newer jQuery versions are more compatible with ES6 promises than others.

Comment: @Bergi - Except the learning about always having a `.catch()` that at least logs so you can log and see your own programming errors is perhaps more useful than just closing.  I dup many, but sometimes some direct explanation for the OP's specific issue is more useful to everyone than a dup.

Comment: Unfortunately there was a typo, but it was in creating the simplified version for posting here. I added the catch and that throws an error that catch is not a function. I think the problem is that some of my other code is still relying on jQuery Deffered and some is using Promise.  So it is good to know that what I have should work if it really is turtles all the way down.

Comment: @Rothrock - Well, if you have a mixture of jQuery promises and ES6 promise calls in here and can't tell us what is what, that makes it pretty hard for us to help you.  We'd also need to know what jQuery version you're using as some are more compatible with ES6 promises than others.

Comment: @Rothrock - You can wrap any jQuery promises with `Promise.resolve()` and that will convert them to ES6 standard promises which will work with `.catch()`.  So, for example, `Promise.resolve(firstNetworkCall()).then(...).catch(...)`.